# No me accede a mi proyecto .net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Buenas he creado un protecto mvc con el comando

```
 dotnet new mvc
```

Estoy en Centos 7

luego compilo y ejecuto con

```
dotnet run
```

info Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as       key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /home
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Pero al entrar desde fuera poniendo la ip me dice servidor no encontrado estoy en la misma red http://192.168.1.200:5000/

los firewall estan bajados  no se que puede ser alguna idea ???

Comment: pero si accedes de forma local con http://localhost:5000, ingresa? recuerda que para habilitar el acceso externo no es directo, debes configurarlo, es mas si estas en linux quizas debas hostear en nginx, porque el server que inicias desde consola no permite el acceso remoto

Comment: a priori si pero yo lo que quiero es acceder desde fuera en teoria deberia de permitirmelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defecto `Kestrel` no permite el acceso remoto lo tienes que configurar y tambien el `firewall de windows` para permitir el acceso.

[External Network Access to Kestrel and IIS Express in ASP.NET Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/28/External-Network-Access-to-Kestrel-and-IIS-Express-in-ASPNET-Core)

[Accessing an ASP .NET Core Web Application Remotely](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/accessing-an-asp-net-core-web-application-remotely/)

Observaras como se redefine la url usando el `UseUrls()` para permitir el acceso

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://myhostname:54691")
        .Build();
```